# Amazon ECR Image is not downloaded when launching an EC2 task on ECS

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I am pretty new to AWS. I have created a private repository in ECR, and uploaded an image to it. I defined a task definition in ECS that uses that image. I have a cluster defined using an autoscale group from EC2, and a service that should run the task with the ECR image. When I scale the autoscale group to 1 instance and in turn go to run my task from my service, the service shows the task starting (status in progress), but it seems that the image is never downloaded.

I have verified that by looking at the summary on the repository, which doesn't show a download for this image but shows downloads for other repositories when they are run, and when I ssh to the instance and poke around on the logs in /var/log I never see any logs where the image is being downloaded or fails to download, etc. Docker only shows the images for the ecs-agent and something else, not the image that I am trying to run. When I use the aws cli to describe the task after it inevitably fails later, the output includes this for the reason the task is stopped:

```
"stopCode": "TaskFailedToStart",
"stoppedAt": "2022-12-20T07:44:46.292000-08:00",
"stoppedReason": "Task failed to start",
"stoppingAt": "2022-12-20T07:44:46.292000-08:00",
```

I have run a different container on this cluster successfully. In this fail case there are no logs that make it to the logstream, no events other than the task starting, I am baffled. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at the "usual suspects": IAM permissions and VPC subnet configuration.